# What is the type of the actions parameter in the alert modifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Say I wanted to create a property such that it can be passed directly to the `actions` parameter of the `alert(_:isPresented:actions:message:)` modifier and can hold multiple buttons. What type would I use to declare that property?

`Button<Text>` works, but I'd like it to hold multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a single view then it should be view builder generating some view (because we talk about generics), like in below demo

```
struct DemoView<Content, Actions>: View where Content: View, Actions: View {
    @Binding var showAlert: Bool

    var actions: () -> Actions    // << here !!
    var content: () -> Content

    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder actions: @escaping () -> Actions, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._showAlert = isPresented
        self.actions = actions         // << here !!
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .alert("Alet", isPresented: $showAlert, actions: actions)
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I'm looking for but another constraint would be that `var actions` is not in a struct that conforms to `View`. This properties of this struct would just be used to parameterize an alert modifier installed on an external view.

Comment: Your implementor of ViewModifier would be similar struct, you can do in it absolutely the same as above.